# Flex logging framework

Tags: apache-flex, logging

I'm looking for a wrapper around the standard Flex Logging framework
I would like to have a "log4j" style logger object declaration and usage. Something like:

```
private static const log:ILogger = getLogger(SomeClass);
```

and the just

```
log.debug("Some {0} happened {1} because of {2}", param1, param2, param3);
```

Also it will be good to have a xml or text configuration, like:

```
org.company.package1=DEBUG
org.company.package2=ERROR
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never used it, but it seems to be what you want: [log4as3](http://code.google.com/p/log4as3/)

Comment: Can't call it lightweight, but satisfies my needs